# Блокировка клавиатуры C#

Tags: c#, клавиатура

Всем привет! Ребята, помоги пожалуйста заблокировать клавиатуру (полностью, не в активном приложении, а вообще) 
 Юзал winAPI user32.dll ф-я BlockInput, но она блокирует полностью ввод (мышку тоже)... мне это не совсем подходит =(

Есть идеи?

Заранее очень благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

Можно посмотреть в сторону глобальных hook-ов для перехвата ввода с клавиатуры. На codeproject есть по этому поводу неплохой [пример](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/CSLLKeyboard.aspx).

Также можно попробовать отключить саму клавиатуру на время. Подробнее об отключении девайсов [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HardwareHelper.aspx) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438371/win32-api-function-to-programatically-enable-disable-device)

Comment: Спасибо =) Этот пример видел! 
 Думал может есть ещё какие-то, пока не изведанные мною способы =)

Comment: Для комментариев есть кнопка "добавить комментарий" ниже каждого ответа.

Comment: Intelevgen: я обновил свой ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо! Предложенные Вами варианты отключения устройств тоже были применены(в другом пункте ТЗ). Для блокировки использовались глобальные хуки =)

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class NativeMethods {

    /// Return Type: BOOL->int
    ///fBlockIt: BOOL->int
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint="BlockInput")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern  bool BlockInput([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt) ;

}

public static void BlockInput(TimeSpan span) {
  try { 
    NativeMethods.BlockInput(true);
    Thread.Sleep(span);
  } finally {
    NativeMethods.BlockInput(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Intelevgen в своем вопросе исключил использование функции ´BlockInput´. Читайте внимательнее